# Update MYSQL value every second on the server

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am trying to make a script that refreshes a value in the database which is bound to a specific registered user. Different with each user ofc.

So for example:
You have an account, and this account has a row in the database called credit, and this credit should increment every second from the registration. (Even if the account is currently logged out.)

Let's say $credit = $credit + 1; (every second).

This is my current code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function UpdateDb()
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","main.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
setTimeout(UpdateDb, 1000);
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload=UpdateDb()>

 <span id="result"><?php $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $query = "SELECT username, credit FROM users WHERE username = '$username'";
    $updater = "UPDATE users SET credit=credit+1 WHERE username = '$username'";
    $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
    mysqli_query($dbc, $updater);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($data) == 1)
    {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($data);
        $credit= $row['credit'];
    }
    echo "<br><br>User: " . $username . "";
    echo "<br>";

    echo "Credit: ". $credit.""; 
?>
    </span>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem with this code is that, it only refreshes the value while the account is logged in.

Comment: Why not store the registration time and compute seconds since registration?

Comment: Remember that it will not only count the time that the user is not logged in, like you want, but also the time what the user is not on your site. Since you didn't state that that's what you wanted I gave you this simple solution.

Comment: does the solution have to be in javascript or is php okay=

Comment: If you're actually trying to update DB values every second you would want to just use a CRON not an AJAX request. The question title should probably be changed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only count the time that the user is actually on your site you could use:

```
<script>
  var startTime = new Date().getTime(); // time in milliseconds

  window.onunload = function()
  {
    var finishTime = new Date().getTime(); // time in milliseconds
    ajaxcall(finishTime-startTime);        // abstract ajax call
  }
</script>
```

Use this on every page. The ajax call should update the database with the amount of time that the user was on the page.

http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/event-attributes/onunload